# How to check logged in user and redirect to specific page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a library to check logged in user. but browser give error

> localhost redirected you too many times.

Here is my custom library

Library

```
class Handler
{

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('session');
        $ci->load->helper('url');
        if ($ci->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('/');
        } else {
            redirect('/login');
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('auth_model');
        $this->handler->is_logged_in();
    }
}
```

Help me to find out the error.

Comment: you redirect the logged user EVERY time to the "/" route. It creats a loop

Comment: @GiacomoMasseroniChiaro so what can i do ?

Comment: you do not have to redirect use if he is logged

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($ci->session->userdata('logged_in') && '/' !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
    redirect('/');
} else {
    redirect('/login');
}
```

or

```
if (!$ci->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
    redirect('/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking Auth in every page, (which is typically what you should do), it will create loops even with the other answer that is posted.

With your logic, everytime I visit a members only page, I will get redirected to the homepage. Are you getting what I am trying to convey?

You should only redirect the non logged in users. Logged in users can continue with the request and should be delivered the view.

```
if (!$ci->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            redirect('/login');
        }
```